# How to calculate average value for an aggregate field in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

[image]
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKgle.png)

In the given image, how to calculate the average of the Values(mean score) that is already being calculated? The fixed include and exclude options doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried `WINDOW_AVG()`

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated field `avg_mean` as

```
WINDOW_AVG(SUM(Mean_score))
```

then calculate it using `table down` or `pane down` whatever is your requirement .